# Как исправить проблему с Dex, появившиеся после удаление Fragment Blank?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-gradle

Моя действия:
1) New Fragment -> Fragment Blank;
2) Delete Fragment_Blank.class and Fragment_Blank.xml ставя все галочки, delete anyway;

После этого у меня проблема:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

Мой app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tj.zmt.mfsysmobile"
        minSdkVersion 14
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleDependency,GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleDependency,GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.snappydb:snappydb-lib:0.5.2'
    compile 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:2.24.0'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile "ru.tinkoff.decoro:decoro:1.1.1"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.redmadrobot:inputmask:3.4.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
```

Поискал решение, не помогает:

```
1)  clean/rebuild; 

2)  android {
        defaultConfig {
           multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Посоветуйте, как исправить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение для своей проблемы, оказалось простым)
В общем изменил версию здесь:

`buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"` на `"27.0.1"`

и 
здесь

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` на `27.0.1`

И все, может кому пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда бывает, возможно вам поможет следующие:

1. синхронизацию в гредл
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Выполните перезагрузку студии и потрите кеш (**File -> Restart and invalidate**)

Если ошибка останется, нужно думать дальше. Желательно на такой случай пользоваться системами контроля версии, чтобы можно было понять, в чем же все-таки дело!

Comment: не сработало, ошибка осталось(

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Amirkhon\Desktop\MFSysMobile\MFSysMobile\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Amirkhon\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar\9b2753c27b77eb98a7d7710279d3cc5b\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

Comment: еще в градле проекта (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1') предлагает обновить до 3.1.3, может нужно обновить?

Comment: а вы уверены, что ошибка появилась именно после создания-удаления фрагмента?

Comment: Да, уверен. Больше ничего...

Comment: сравнить с предыдущим коммитом пробовали?

Comment: Вообще, у меня есть еще одна идея. Последнее время, винда подбрасывает в исходники скрытые файлы .ini - они возникают при удалении/копировании файлов. Из-за этого возникают ошибки компиляции. Проверьте проект на наличие таких файлов (только галочку поставьте отобразить скрытые файлы)